# How to concat string with new line character in typescript

Tags: string, typescript, newline, string-concatenation

I am trying to concat  string and i want to put new line in the output string.
I want to send the same string as email body using mailto so that i can display the string in multiple lines. when I put \n I could see in the dev console its printing with newline as formatted but, not in dom or in email body, i can'y use any html tags to break down to new line..any help here

```
input: line1line2line3line4line5;

I tried : "line1\nline2\nline3\nline4\nline5"

actual output: line1 line2 line3 line4 line5

expected output:
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: updated above  question

Comment: Excatly how do you create your output? Can you show use the code?

Comment: var subject='my subject';
      var body = 'email body'
      var str1 = subject + '\n' + body;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode `\n` to pass it as url param `%0A`

```html
<a href="mailto:test@test.com?body=Hello%2CDear%0AText%0AText%0A" target="_blank">Email</a>
```

If you are using javascript there is `encodeURIComponent` for that.

Comment: @Jayesh Glad I could help. BTW you also need to encode various other characters: commas, question marks, equal signs, etc

Comment: This works because: %0A is ascii char 10, which is the line feed character, which is what \n also represents.